# Echo current filename into a text file ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I normally just browse around and not looking to post questions however I am currently learning how to shell script and I've fallen into a pickle.

At the moment I have a structure of:

```
Main
---Hub1
---Hub2
---Hub3
---Hub4
```

All the way to Hub20.

What i want the structure to be is:

```
Main
---Hub1
--------Notes_1.txt >> "The <file_name> belongs to <user> and was created in Hub1"
---Hub2
--------Notes_2.txt >> "The <file_name> belongs to <user> and was created in Hub2"
```

and so on.
At the moment my code is looking like this

```
i=1
until (($i>20))
filename="~/Main/Hub${i}/Notes_$i.txt"
do 
touch ~/Main/Hub${i}/Notes_$i.txt
echo "The $(basename -- "$filename") belongs to $USER was created in the Hub${i}" >> ~/Main/Hub${i}.txt
((i++))
done
```

Its not doing what it needs to be doing and I just cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I am aware it's not formatted right. It may be a simply solution or maybe I am completely off. I want to get it working before I start moving it around. Any advice would be great. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have `$` in `"filename"` so it's not using the variable. Also, `~` is not expanded when it's in quotes.

Comment: Should `~Main` be `~/Main`?

Comment: You shouldn't have a variable between the `until` condition and `do`.

Comment: Yes, Apologises it is indeed `~/Main` and I also do have `$` a in `filename`. I have now updated it on the question. With the variable, I think it originally was above the `until` have it didn't work.

Comment: @HulkisTRASH : Note that the `~`  inside `filename="~/Main/Hub${i}/Notes_$i.txt"` won't expand to your home directory, because expansion is inhibited by the double quotes.  Drop the quotes, or use `$HOME` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a brace range instead of `until`.

Don't put the pathname in quotes, that prevents expanding `~`.

You need `$` before `filename` in the `echo` statement to expand the variable.

```
for i in {1..20}; do
    filename=~/Main/Hub${i}/Notes_$i.txt
    touch "$filename"
    echo "The $(basename -- "$filename") belongs to $USER was created in the Hub${i}" >> ~/Main/Hub${i}.txt
done
```

Comment: This has worked and successfully added the filename as I need it! Thank you! If you have time, what would be the difference between using the until and brace range? How come this worked better than the `until`? Are they able to work in unison?

Comment: You had invalid syntax because of the variable assignment before `do`.

Comment: The variable assignment should be after `do`.